# Multiple Kernel Sizes in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am working on developing a character embedding and for that, I have employed a 1D-CNN (reference: article on [TowardsDataScience](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-definitive-guide-to-bidaf-part-2-word-embedding-character-embedding-and-contextual-c151fc4f05bb)).

The article attached above considers multiple kernel/filter sizes for the convolution operation.

My question is: **Is there a way in Pytorch using which we can directly feed multiple kernel sizes as an argument and get the result?**

Answer (score 1):

There is no single module that accepts a list of kernel sizes, but you can easily build one yourself. You basically need to create multiple convolutional blocks acting in parallel, here's one way to do it:

```py
class MultiScaleConv1d(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_channels: int, out_channels: int, kernel_sizes: Iterable[int] = (3, 5, 7)):
        # iterate the list and create a ModuleList of single Conv1d blocks
        self.kernels = nn.ModuleList()
        for k in kernel_sizes:
            self.kernels.append(nn.Conv1d(in_channels, out_channels, k))

    def forward(self, inputs):
        # now you can build a single output from the list of convs
        out = [module(inputs) for module in self.kernels]
        # you can return a list, or even build a single tensor, like so
        return torch.cat(out, dim=1)
```